# Cocoa: simple tabs

Tags: cocoa, user-interface

Does any one know how to create a tab bar like this:
[image]

I mean that simple tab, without rounded corners or texture, with "Untitled" string

Is this a standard control? Or is there an open source library for such tabs? I think I saw it in a open source editor or something but totally forgot which one.

Answer (score 1):

There are no doubt other ways to do this, but one I've used often in the past is PSMTabBarControl. It's been around for a while, and forked a few times. The version at https://github.com/dorianj/PSMTabBarControl can be used with Xcode 4.

Documentation can be found http://www.positivespinmedia.com/dev/PSMTabBarControl.html.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it looks exactly like that screenshot. I know I saw a control precisely like the one above, I just forgot where.